# Intuitive definition of scaling random variables by a constant?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

From how I understand scaling discrete random variables, we are multiplying all members in the set by the scaling constant.

I.E if our random variable X = {1,2,3,4} and our scaling factor is $\alpha = 2$ then 
$\alpha X$ = {2,4,6,8}

If we do this with a binomial random variable, however what does this exactly mean?

Answer (score 1):

Your notation writes a random variable as the set of values. Actual definition is a real-valued function on the set of all possible outcomes of an experiment. (there are technicalities about measurable functions which I am ignoring).  For any function a scalar multiple of that function makes sense.

In the specific example you quote: consider an experiment where you are tossing $n$ independent coins each has probability $1-p$ of coming up with tails. Assume tail has value zero. And assume the coins  have on the other side instead of head have a specific number $\alpha$ written on them. Now the random variable defined as "total value shown when $n$ coins are tossed" is the one you are interested.